# Laravel full name check if it's actually full

Tags: php, laravel

How can I check in Laravel default registration form if user actually input full name in the name field, instead of just first name? I don't want to modify form just for that, to have first and last name. Also, I'm asking if there is some check option built in, but if not I can use pure PHP check..

Comment: What is logic or definition of `full name` ?  There would be name like `xxxx xxxx` or `xxxx xxxx xxxxx` both are full name.

Comment: Please define `full name`.

Comment: Yes, but full name is not only `xxxxx`, user can input just it's first name in name fileld

Comment: Still not clear what you are saying ? Can you share some format for name?

Comment: Not every one in the world has a “first” name and a “last” name. As @C2486 says, some people might have three names, some people only  have a single name; so your statement, “but full name is not only `xxxxx`” is incorrect. Read this for more insight: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: if(count(explode(' ', trim(request()->name))) > 1){
echo 'Its full name';
}else{
echo 'Not full name';
}

Answer (score 1):

No there is not such an option built into Laravel.

You would have to write your own function.

But the first question to ask is how to determine whether a name is a full name or not? You can assume that a full name is two strings with a space in between.
However people have a first name which might consist of two parts, or a last name in two parts. Chinese names start with the last name and end with the first name.

Generally when creating registration form you divide the name in 2 inputs, first and last. This is also much better when persisting to the database.

Imagine for example if you want to retrieve users by last name and sort them alphabetically. If you store the full name instead of first and last name separately this will be a headache.

Comment: `Generally when creating registration form you divide the name in 2 inputs, first and last.` Still that isn't enough. People with middle names exist :D

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden people like you with a tussenvoegsel :P

Comment: Yes, and talking about full names, for me that would include christian names aswell. So my full name consist of 6 parts and 5 spaces :D